# Tortoise SVN for existing VS2012 project/folder?

Tags: visual-studio, svn, tortoisesvn

I am trying to attach a Tortoise SVN repository to an already-existing VS2010 project folder. However, T-SVN is saying it requires an empty folder. What is the best way to proceed with this? Simply cut and paste the VS project files, create the repository and then re-cut and paste the Visual Studio files back??

Comment: what you say. Or, create a new repository in some other folder and move the .svn folder into your existing one.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way would be to have the working copy of the repository stand as sub-folder in project folder (or even solution folder). Files that are part of the project, but not part of the repository, would then be separated from repository files.

In most cases there is no compelling reason to do otherwise.